# I have custom Javascript fadein function which looses cleartype of text after effect fadein in IE 7

Tags: javascript

Sorry guys.. I am not familiar with JavaScript anymore but I need to add clear type which can make text anti-aliased in IE7. I found some similar questions but. the problem is I don't know the right place to paste the code I get.

My script as follow

```
// JavaScript Document
var CurrentDivIndex=0;
var TimeOutValue;
var btn;
var TimeToFade = 1000.0;
function ShowDivSlideShow()
{
 try 
 {
  if(CurrentDivIndex == 5)
   CurrentDivIndex=0;

  CurrentDivIndex++;  
  //alert("Banner" + CurrentDivIndex);
  //alert(CurrentDivIndex);
  var Indexer=1;
  while(Indexer<6)
  {


   var DivToShow=document.getElementById("Banner" + Indexer);
   DivToShow.style.display = "none";
   btn=document.getElementById("btnb" + Indexer);
   btn.setAttribute("class","none");

      Indexer++;

  }



  var DivToShow=document.getElementById("Banner" + CurrentDivIndex);
  DivToShow.style.display = "block";
  btn=document.getElementById("btnb" + CurrentDivIndex);
  btn.setAttribute("class","activeSlide");
//  btn.className="activeSlide";
  fadeIn();
  TimeOutValue=setTimeout("ShowDivSlideShow()",6000);

 }
 catch(err)
 {
  alert(err)
 }
}



function ShowCustomDiv(CurrentDivIndexRec)
{

 clearTimeout(TimeOutValue)
 CurrentDivIndex=CurrentDivIndexRec

  var Indexer=1;
 while(Indexer<6)
 {
  if(CurrentDivIndex==Indexer)
  {
   Indexer++;
   continue;
  }

  var DivToShow=document.getElementById("Banner" + Indexer);
  DivToShow.style.display = "none";
  btn=document.getElementById("btnb" + Indexer);
   btn.setAttribute("class","none");
     Indexer++;

 }

 var DivToShow=document.getElementById("Banner" + CurrentDivIndex);
  DivToShow.style.display = "block";
  btn=document.getElementById("btnb" + CurrentDivIndex);
  btn.setAttribute("class","activeSlide");
  btn.className="activeSlide"
  fadeIn();
}


function ShowDivSlideShowWithTimeOut(CurrentDivIndexRec)
{

 clearTimeout(TimeOutValue)
 CurrentDivIndex=CurrentDivIndexRec;
 var Indexer=1;
  while(Indexer<6)
  {
  if(CurrentDivIndex==Indexer)
  {
   Indexer++;
   continue;
  }

  var DivToShow=document.getElementById("Banner" + Indexer);
  DivToShow.style.display = "none";
  btn=document.getElementById("btnb" + Indexer);
  btn.setAttribute("class","none");
  Indexer++;

  }


 var DivToShow=document.getElementById("Banner" + CurrentDivIndexRec);
  DivToShow.style.display = "block";
  btn=document.getElementById("btnb" + CurrentDivIndexRec);
  btn.setAttribute("class","activeSlide");


 TimeOutValue=setTimeout("ShowDivSlideShow()",6000);
}

function ShowCustomDivOnClick(CurrentDivIndexRec)
{

 clearTimeout(TimeOutValue)
 CurrentDivIndex=CurrentDivIndexRec;

  var Indexer=1;
  while(Indexer<6)
  {
  if(CurrentDivIndex==Indexer)
  {
   Indexer++;
   continue;
  }

  var DivToShow=document.getElementById("Banner" + Indexer);
  DivToShow.style.display = "none";

  btn=document.getElementById("btnb" + Indexer);
  btn.setAttribute("class","none");
     Indexer++;

  }


 var DivToShow=document.getElementById("Banner" + CurrentDivIndexRec);
  DivToShow.style.display = "block";

  btn=document.getElementById("btnb" + CurrentDivIndexRec);
  btn.setAttribute("class","activeSlide");

  fadeIn();
 TimeOutValue=setTimeout("ShowDivSlideShow()",6000);
}

function setOpacity(level) {
  element=document.getElementById("Banner" + CurrentDivIndex);
  element.style.opacity = level;
  element.style.MozOpacity = level;
  element.style.KhtmlOpacity = level;
  element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (level * 100) + ");";
}

var duration = 300;  /* 1000 millisecond fade = 1 sec */
var steps = 10;       /* number of opacity intervals   */
var delay = 6000;     /* 5 sec delay before fading out */

function fadeIn(){
  for (i = 0; i <= 1; i += (1 / steps)) {
    setTimeout("setOpacity(" + i + ")", i * duration);
  }
 // setTimeout("fadeOut()", delay);
}

function fadeOut() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 1; i += (1 / steps)) {
    setTimeout("setOpacity(" + (1 - i) + ")", i * duration);
  }
  setTimeout("fadeIn()", duration);
}
```

//end of script

Now I am very confused where to add :

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
    cleartype:  1 // enable cleartype corrections 
});

or

$('#fadingElement').fadeIn(2000, function(){
 $(this).css('filter','');
});
```

so it will work... Please Help me...

Comment: Include this link in your page http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/tune.aspx

Comment: I can't force user to edit his windows settings.

Comment: Clear Type is an OS level technology, you can't enable or disable it from your website. If it's off and you *could* enable it, would you want to calibrate it for the user as well? What if the user doesn't use an LCD, will you turn it back off? Can you tell the difference?

Comment: though Clear-type is enabled in windows 7, I can see text sharp in IE7

Comment: You should describe what your actual problem is, possibly show screenshots. "Turning on Clear Type" is the wrong solution to look for.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. Just replace all of your text with pre-rendered versions. If your site has a fixed-width layout, take a screenshot of it and embed the image in your page. Using pre-rendered images is always the clear and definitive solution.